# How to update a specific Text view present inside a list of Card Views

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have used a Recycler View and created a list of Card Views. Within each Card View, there are 3 Text Views. Now I have a Button in my Action Bar called Start. I want that when I press the start button, the 2nd Text View of only the 1st Card View be updated. How do I do that? Please someone help me out. I am a beginner in Android Studio and sorry if my question is silly, but please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class, on method onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position): you can check if the position==0, then you are working with the first card view, if so, find the second text view using findViewById and set it's text as you wish. 
This is a general explanation, if you want more details, don't hesitate to ask and you might attach some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing from phone, sorry for missing code formatting.
You can use next code to get your cardview from recycler view and find its child by position:

CardView v = (CardView) recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(0);

TextView tv = v.getChildAt(1);

tv.setText("text");

P.s. place this code inside the OnClickListener.